# SailsJS: Server doesn't seem to be starting, error on AWS

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, sails.js

Locally, my application works fine.

But on AWS, server breaks with following message:

```
error: Server doesn't seem to be starting.
error: Perhaps something else is already running on port 8080 with hostname ip-172-31-20-240?
```

I **run** it as `sudo node app.js`.

I set my port and host like this:

```
module.exports = {
  environment: process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development',
  port: process.env.PORT || 8080,
  host: 'ip-172-31-20-240'
};
```

And I got host, by doing `'echo $HOSTNAME'` on server.

I also did these commands:

```
sudo iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --sport 80 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
```

I'm not sure what else I'm missing?

Comment: Have you tried other ports?

Comment: Sure, I tried 1337, tried with `sails lift --port=1234`, etc, but without luck. Not sure what's wrong. Also, if I run it without `sudo`, Grunt is complaining when cleaning tmp folder.

Comment: sorry if this is obvious, but did you make sure your security group allows access to port 80/8080?